# Python. Поиск по матрице, считанной из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вечера. Сижу над разными задачами. Сейчас работаю с матрицами. 
Такой вопрос,как реализовать поиск по матрице,которая читается с файла как в моем коде ниже?
В elif'е реализовано то,что я хочу сделать и в if,но пока не додумал что да как.

```
  r = int(input())

if r == 1:
    with open('matrix1.txt') as f:
        matrix = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in f.readlines()]
        print (matrix)


    print("Число рёбер:",k)

elif r == 2:
    print("Введите кол-во точек графа: ")   
    M=N=int(input())
    print("Заполните матрицу смежности:")
    matrix=[]
    matrix = [[int(input())
       for x in range(N)] for y in range(M)]
    print(matrix)

    k=0
    for x in range(N):
        for y in range(M):
           if matrix[x][y] == 1:
               k +=  1             
    print("Число рёбер:",k)
```

Comment: так вы все уже сделали, просто for пройдитесь по списку в списке

Comment: Я туплю под ночь,а как оно будет выглядеть? Можете подсобить немножко?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

может как то так

```py
k = 0
if r == 1:
    with open('matrix1.txt') as f:
        matrix = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in f.readlines()]
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
                k += 1 if matrix[i][j] == 1 else 0
elif r == 2:  
    M = N = int(input("Введите кол-во точек графа: "))
    print("Заполните матрицу смежности:")
    matrix = [[int(input()) for x in range(N)] for y in range(M)]
    for x in range(N):
        for y in range(M):
           k += 1 if matrix[i][j] == 1 else 0 

print('Число ребер -> {}\n Матрица:\n{}'.format(k, matrix))
```

Comment: Да,что-то такое. Спасибо за помощь)